# How to remove the unchecked checkbox parent element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

[**My Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/175ro8dw/11/)

I need to remove the unchecked checkbox items.  I dont know where I'm going wrong. Some of the items only deleted I don't know why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remove').click(function(){

  var classlength = $('.showdropdowninv').find('.classname').length;
  for(var i=0;i< classlength; i++){
    if($('.showdropdowninv').find(".classname").eq(i).attr('checked') == true){
    } else {
      $('.showdropdowninv').find(".classname").eq(i).closest('li').remove();
    } //else close
  }
 });
});
```

Just check the some of the checkbox and click remove link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onclick of remove link loop through all the unchecked checkboxes having class 'classname' using `$("input.classname:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(){` and remove the parent of it using `$(this).parent().remove();`.

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remove').click(function(){
    $("input.classname:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="showdropdowninv" style="display: block;">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="selectall"> Select All </li>

  <li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> System Name
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SYSTEM_NAME">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Version Consistency
  <form class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="VERSION">
    <select name="op" class="xsmall">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
  </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Patch Level Consistency
  <form class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="PATCH">
    <select name="op" class="xsmall">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
  </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Recovery Mode Consitency
  <form class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="RECOVERY_MODE_CONSITENCY">
    <select name="op" class="xsmall">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
  </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Maintenance Plans
  <form class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MAINTENANCE_PLANS">
    <select name="op" class="xsmall">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
  </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Permissions &amp; Security Consistency
  <form class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SECURITY">
    <select name="op" class="xsmall">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
  </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Tuning or Parameter Alignment
  <form class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="TUNING">
    <select name="op" class="xsmall">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
  </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Monitoring Agents
  <form class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MONITORING_AGENTS">
    <select name="op" class="xsmall">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
  </form></li>                </ul>


<a href="javascript:;" id="remove">Remove selected</a>
```

Comment: i need to delete the uncheck checkobx in it how can i do that ?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to delete the items that are checked, and this does that

Comment: @depperm yes because initially SO asked for it. But please check now I have changed my answer. Now unchecked checkboxes will removed.

Comment: @RahulPatel you remove the first one which doesn't have the class `classname`

Comment: @depperm ohhh I see. Updated answer. Now onwards unchecked checkboxes with class "classname" will be removed

Answer (score 2):

Loop over all the checkboxes with `$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){}`. Check for the checked checkboxes using `$(v).prop('checked')`and then find their parent and remove them using `$(this).parent().remove();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remove').click(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
  
   if(!$(v).prop('checked')) {
     $(this).parent().remove();
    }
  })
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="showdropdowninv" style="display: block;">
                  <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="selectall"> Select All </li>
      
      <li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> System Name
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SYSTEM_NAME">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Version Consistency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="VERSION">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Patch Level Consistency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="PATCH">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Recovery Mode Consitency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="RECOVERY_MODE_CONSITENCY">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Maintenance Plans
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MAINTENANCE_PLANS">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Permissions &amp; Security Consistency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SECURITY">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Tuning or Parameter Alignment
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="TUNING">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Monitoring Agents
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MONITORING_AGENTS">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li>                </ul>
      
      
      <a href="javascript:;" id="remove">Remove selected</a>
```

Comment: i need to delete the uncheck checkobx in it how can i do that ?

Comment: Negate the if condition simply `if(!$(v).prop('checked'))`

Comment: your question sounded like you needed to  delete the checked checkboxes. Anyways i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `classname` class and then remove those elements without the property `checked`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    $('.classname').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="showdropdowninv" style="display: block;">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="selectall"> Select All </li>

  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> System Name
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SYSTEM_NAME">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Version Consistency
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="VERSION">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Patch Level Consistency
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="PATCH">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Recovery Mode Consitency
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="RECOVERY_MODE_CONSITENCY">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Maintenance Plans
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MAINTENANCE_PLANS">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Permissions &amp; Security Consistency
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SECURITY">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Tuning or Parameter Alignment
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="TUNING">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li class="togglelihere">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Monitoring Agents
    <form class="hide">
      <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MONITORING_AGENTS">
      <select name="op" class="xsmall">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>


<a href="javascript:;" id="remove">Remove selected</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Remove items which are unchekced  
$('input[type="checkbox"].classname')
    .not(":checked")
    .parent('li')
    .remove(); 

//To remove checked items only
$('input[type="checkbox"].classname:checked')
    .parent('li')
    .remove();
```

Try this snippet.

I don't think any each loop required to achieve the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remove').click(function(){
    //Remove items which are unchecked
    $('input[type="checkbox"].classname')
      .not(":checked")
      .parent('li')
      .remove(); 
  });
  //Check all functionality
  $('.selectall').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"].classname')
        .prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});

//To remove checked items only
//$('input[type="checkbox"].classname:checked').parent('li').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="showdropdowninv" style="display: block;">
                  <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="selectall"> Select All </li>
      
      <li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> System Name
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SYSTEM_NAME">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Version Consistency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="VERSION">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Patch Level Consistency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="PATCH">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Recovery Mode Consitency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="RECOVERY_MODE_CONSITENCY">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Maintenance Plans
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MAINTENANCE_PLANS">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Permissions &amp; Security Consistency
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="SECURITY">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Tuning or Parameter Alignment
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="TUNING">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li><li class="togglelihere"><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="classname" id="idflesd"> Monitoring Agents
                        <form class="hide">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="MONITORING_AGENTS">
                        <select name="op" class="xsmall">
                        <option value="equal">=</option>
                        <option value="notEqual">!=</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="small" name="val">
   </form></li>                </ul>
      
      
      <a href="javascript:;" id="remove">Remove selected</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `has` and `not` selectors

```
$("li:has(:checkbox:not(:checked))").remove()
```

Comment: while this is good his first `li` element does not have class `classname` and this will remove the first element

Comment: so li.xxxxx can be added

Comment: not before the `has` since the `classname` is for the checkbox not the li

Comment: It has the common class `togglelihere`

Comment: you could change it to `$("li:has(:checkbox.classname:not(:checked))").remove()` and it would work